# MDX calculate average in ALL

Tags: mdx

In the `ALL` column I want the average of the total income if it is 2010 and holiday, but instead I get the sum of all incomes. Maybe somebody can help?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Income] AS 
    [Measures].[Average Income] 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = '#.## €' 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Income]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
      [Order Date].[Date].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Measures].[Income]
       ,[Order Date].[Holiday].&[True]
      )
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [xxxxx]
WHERE 
  [Order Date].[Year].&[2010];
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the native AVG aggregation instead of SUM?

Answer (score 0):

Will need to test but does this additional measure work?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AvgIncome] AS 
    Avg
    (
      Filter
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [Order Date].[Date].MEMBERS)
       ,(
          [Measures].[Income]
         ,[Order Date].[Holiday].&[True]
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Average Income]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Income] AS 
    [Measures].[Average Income] 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = '#.## €' 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Income]
   ,[Measures].[AvgIncome]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
      [Order Date].[Date].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Measures].[Income]
       ,[Order Date].[Holiday].&[True]
      )
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [xxxxx]
WHERE 
  [Order Date].[Year].&[2010];
```